# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve ‘xxxx’ in ‘xxxx’ resolve ‘xxxx’

Tags: webpack

I saw similar issues as this but couldn't find a solution for me maybe because my webpack.config.js is different.
Important to note is that I only get this problem on MacOS when executing "webpack --display-error-details" on the root of the folder where webpack.config.js.

[Full source code here](https://github.com/AccountGo/accountgo)

**webpack.config.js**

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='Run - Development' />
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var buildDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/scripts');
var scriptsDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild');

var config = {
    entry: {
        index: scriptsDir + '/home' + '/index',
        "sales/salesorder": scriptsDir + '/sales/salesorder',
        "quotations/salesquotation": scriptsDir + '/quotations/salesquotation',
        "sales/salesinvoice": scriptsDir + '/sales/salesinvoice',
        "purchasing/purchaseorder": scriptsDir + '/purchasing/purchaseorder',
        "purchasing/purchaseinvoice": scriptsDir + '/purchasing/purchaseinvoice',
        "financials/journalentry": scriptsDir + '/financials/journalentry',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
    output: {
        path: buildDir,
        filename: '[name].chunk.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        })
    ],
    externals: {
        'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV === 'production' ?
            {
                apiUrl: "https://accountgoapi.azurewebsites.net/"
                //apiUrl: "http://localhost:5000/"
            } :
            {
                apiUrl: "https://accountgoapi.azurewebsites.net/"
                //apiUrl: "http://localhost:5000/"
            })
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "accountgoweb",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "4.2.15",
    "ts-loader": "3.5.0",
    "tsd": "0.6.5",
    "typescript": "2.7.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "mobx": "3.5.1",
    "mobx-react": "4.4.1",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "d3": "4.13.0",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "ag-grid": "16.0.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom-factories": "1.0.2",
    "knockout-mapping": "2.6.0",
    "knockout": "3.5.0-beta",
    "accounting": "0.4.1",
    "jspdf": "1.3.5",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-alpha.9"
  }
}
```

**Full Error**

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice'
>   in '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb' resolve
>   '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice'
>   in '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb'   using
>   description file:
>   /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/package.json (relative
>   path: .)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>       using description file: /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/package.json (relative
>   path: ./wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice.js
>   doesn't exist
>         .jsx
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice.jsx
>   doesn't exist
>         .tsx
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice.tsx
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesinvoice
>   doesn't exist
>
> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder'
>   in '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb' resolve
>   '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder'
>   in '/Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb'   using
>   description file:
>   /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/package.json (relative
>   path: .)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>       using description file: /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/package.json (relative
>   path: ./wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder.js
>   doesn't exist
>         .jsx
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder.jsx
>   doesn't exist
>         .tsx
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder.tsx
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           /Users/Marvs/source/accountgo/src/AccountGoWeb/wwwroot/libs/tsxbuild/sales/salesorder
>   doesn't exist

Comment: In the `buildDir` and `scriptsDir` variables, try removing the `.` at the beginning of the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The tsx files must be converted first to js and move to tsxbuild folder. I thought the webpack (I'm not experience in webpack) will do this conversion for me. But moving of files is handled by tsconfig.json. Need to install typescript first, then run "tsc" on the folder where tsconfig.json located. Now the webpack command works.